# Calculate the sunlight direction according to the current time and position on the earth

Tags: android, date, gps, augmented-reality

How can I calculate the position of the sun according to the current time and position on the earth?  I am currently adding light-sources to an Augmented Reality framework on Android and it would be great to know where to set the "sun".  I think there are a lot of factors but an approximation would be enough for now I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at the [noaa site](http://www.srrb.noaa.gov/highlights/sunrise/calcdetails.html), they give you a spreadsheet that gives you the results you want.